# Q-learning table efficiency

Tags: optimization, machine-learning

So I am trying to create a Q-learning algorithm to solve simple games, starting with tic-tac-toe.

I would like to do so without completely eating away my memory, but all the examples online create a 2 dimensionnal array of dimensions [number_states, number_actions]. But just for tic-tac-toe we have 3^9 possible states (I ignore the impossible ones since the goal is to implement the algorithm to harder games where getting invalid states is not viable), and 9 actions. And this scales exponentially with bigger grid games.

Is there a smarter way to create the table containing the Q-values?